# How to configure Context using PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

Actully i am a java developer and new to PHP, I am using Code Ignitor as a frame work for my project.Setup site on my local machine. And accessing site using following URL.

**http://localhost/businesscaliber/index.php/home**

Where home is HomeController. here i want to context as

**http://localhost/businesscaliber** rather than above URL.

Answer (score 2):

You need to rewrite the htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

More info: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) feature in CodeIgniter.

under application/config/routes.php file,

modify the the following line into this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
```

then follow the guide to remove index.php found here: [CodeIgniter URLs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .htaccess and mod_rewrite for Apache.
More info here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

For a more Detailed Explanation have a look at the Codeigniter Wiki

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/